# Standardizing OR from logistic regressions with log-transformed variables for meta-analysis?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, meta-analysis, nonlinear-regression

I´m trying to meta-analyze odds ratios from logistic regressions; s**ome of which log-transformed the independent variable first**. 
(i.e. some studies present an OR per +1 in the independent variable, and others present OR per b% increase in the independent variable, where b is the base of the logtransformation).
I know the standarization to take all this ORs to the same effect meassure (OR per +1 indep. variable) is quite common in linear regressions coefficients (see https://doi.org/10.1186/s12874-017-0322-8)
Are you aware of any method posible for **logistic regressions**?